# how to amend a code to get query from external and save result to external

Tags: ruby

I have a code which looks like this

```
require 'net/http'

base = 'www.uniprot.org'
tool = 'mapping'
params = {
  'from' => 'ACC+ID', 'to' => 'P_ENTREZGENEID', 'format' => 'tab',
  'query' => 'A0A0K3AVS5 A0A0K3AVV4 A0A0K3AW32 A0A0K3AWP0'
}

http = Net::HTTP.new base
$stderr.puts "Submitting...\n";
response = http.request_post '/' + tool + '/',
  params.keys.map {|key| key + '=' + params[key]}.join('&')

loc = nil
while response.code == '302'
  loc = response['Location']
  response = http.request_get loc
end

while loc
  wait = response['Retry-After'] or break
  $stderr.puts "Waiting (#{wait})...\n";
  sleep wait.to_i
  response = http.request_get loc
end

response.value # raises http error if not 2xx
puts response.body
```

which gives me what I need. however, I have two questions

1- How to load a query list instead I parse it into the code ? lets say I save a txt file with all the query i want to the desktop of a mac

2- How to export the output ?

If I have

```
B2D6P1
G5EC52
B2FDA8-2
B2MZB1
B3CJ34
B3CKG1
B3GWA1
```

what @tadman showed gives me the answer 
however, I have the following

```
B2D6P1
G5EC52;B2D6P4
B2FDA8-2;B2FDA8
B2MZB1;P18834
B3CJ34
B3CKG1
B3GWA1;Q8I7K5
```

and the answer is like below

```
B2D6P1  rmd-2
G5EC52  tlf-1
B2D6P4  tlf-1
B2FDA8  smc-3
B2MZB1  col-14
P18834  col-14
B3CJ34  gcn-1
B3CKG1  urm-1
B3GWA1  nono-1
Q8I7K5  nono-1
```

what I want is that if I have two entries in each row (separated with ;) leading to the similar output , it gives me only one , otherwise give me as many as they have for example in above example , my desire output is

```
B2D6P1                rmd-2
G5EC52;B2D6P4         tlf-1
B2FDA8-2;B2FDA8       smc-3
B2MZB1;P18834         col-14
B3CJ34                gcn-1
B3CKG1                urm-1
B3GWA1;Q8I7K5         nono-1
```

is this possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading query data:

```
query = File.readlines('ids.txt').map(&:chomp).join(' ')
```

That way you can have them on separate lines, easier to edit, and they're space separated when submitted.

That makes your params look like:

```
params = {
  'query' => query,
  ...
}
```

Writing data:

```
File.open('output.txt', 'w') do |f|
  f.write(response.body)
end
```

That's all there is to it. If it's a string, or can be converted to a string, you can write it to a file.

Comment: is giving me what I asked. however, I would like to know if you can help me with something which i don't know how to handle. please look in my question. i added something if you think it is not possible then i accept your answer

Comment: If you have a space-delimited file: `query = File.read('input.txt')`. Even easier.

Comment: no no, the input you gave works like a charm , that is not the case. the output is the case. look at above now, I put it there because it is easier for you to read . however, I already liked your answer and once you say it can be done or not. i accept your answer anyway

Comment: Please ask another question about the formatting issue. That's a valid problem but it's best addressed separately.

Comment: I asked a separate question then and I accepted your answer . Thanks man

Comment: here is the new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38941533/how-to-format-an-output-using-several-entries-in-parsing