# how to format an output using several entries in parsing

Tags: ruby

I recently asked a question and the answer was very good by @tadman   [how to amend a code to get query from external and save result to external](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38940863/how-to-amend-a-code-to-get-query-from-external-and-save-result-to-external)

If I give entities like below

```
B2D6P1
G5EC52
B2FDA8-2
B2MZB1
B3CJ34
B3CKG1
B3GWA1
```

what @tadman showed gives me the answer but it is only valid if I have one enters per row. if I have two or more entries per row, the output will be different for example I have the following

```
B2D6P1
G5EC52;B2D6P4
B2FDA8-2;B2FDA8
B2MZB1;P18834
B3CJ34
B3CKG1
B3GWA1;Q8I7K5
```

and the answer is like below

```
B2D6P1  rmd-2
G5EC52  tlf-1
B2D6P4  tlf-1
B2FDA8  smc-3
B2MZB1  col-14
P18834  col-14
B3CJ34  gcn-1
B3CKG1  urm-1
B3GWA1  nono-1
Q8I7K5  nono-1
```

what I want is that if I have two entries in each row (separated with ;) leading to the similar output , it gives me only one , otherwise give me as many as they have for example in above example , my desire output is

```
B2D6P1                rmd-2
G5EC52;B2D6P4         tlf-1
B2FDA8-2;B2FDA8       smc-3
B2MZB1;P18834         col-14
B3CJ34                gcn-1
B3CKG1                urm-1
B3GWA1;Q8I7K5         nono-1
```

is this possible ?